# React does not recognize the `hasCreate` prop on a DOM element

Tags: react-admin

Since migration to 4.2.7, all my list have an issue :

Warning: React does not recognize the `hasCreate` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `hascreate` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
at div
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15429:66
at Toolbar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49221:82)
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15429:66
at TopToolbar
at ListActions (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:62975:25)
at div
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:15429:66
at Toolbar (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:49221:82)

How to solve this?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> in the most of the cases its happend when you add your custom prop to exist component so the DOM is doesn’t know what is it, so you can add $ like in this example:

```
const Component = styled.div`
   font-size: ${({ $isMobile }) => ($isMobile ? '9px' : '16px')};
`

<Component $isMobile={true} />
```